# A variation of the knapsack problem where some items must be included but don't count towards the objective

Tags: python, linear-programming, knapsack-problem

I am trying to solve a variation of the 0/1 knapsack problem where n items must be picked, but only k < n items' values are counted towards the objective function.

My idea was to set up two vectors of binary variables, x and y - x denoting which n items are picked, and y denoting which k items are counted towards the objective - however my problem is ensuring that y is a subset of x.

I am using the python mip library, and here is the code I have so far (a slightly modified version of the knapsack example in the mip documentation):

```
from mip import Model, xsum, maximize, BINARY

values = [10, 13, 18, 31, 7, 15, 8, 11, 3, 9, 13, 12, 11, 6, 18, 11, 18, 13, 12, 11]
weights = [11, 15, 20, 24, 9, 16, 12, 3, 6, 9, 17, 13, 20, 9, 32, 14, 19, 20, 12, 13]

max_weight = 200
I = range(len(weights))
m = Model("knapsack")

x = [m.add_var(var_type=BINARY) for i in I]
y = [m.add_var(var_type=BINARY) for i in I]

m += xsum(x[i] for i in I) == 15 # n
m += xsum(y[i] for i in I) == 11 # k
m += xsum(weights[i] * x[i] for i in I) <= max_weight

m.objective = maximize(xsum(values[i] * y[i] for i in I))

# `m += xsum(x[i] * y[i] for i in I) == 11` doesn't work
m.optimize()

selected_x = [i for i in I if x[i].x >= 0.99]
selected_y = [i for i in I if y[i].x >= 0.99]
print("selected items: {}".format(selected_x))
print("selected items: {}".format(selected_y))

#Output:
# selected items: [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
# selected items: [1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 11, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Any help would be great, thank you.

edit: for anyone finding this in the future, simply adding

```
for i in I:
    m += x[i] >= y[i]
```

works perfectly.

Comment: Not so easy. See [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2020/06/select-n-items-but-optimize-for-best-k.html).

Comment: Ah, exactly what I needed, and so simple to implement. Thank you so much!